# Can the Windows fork of Caffe be used for object detection?

Tags: windows, caffe, object-detection, pycaffe

I've installed Caffe on my Windows computer but from what I can tell online most projects that use Caffe to do object detection are using some other forks of Caffe like NvCaffe or the SSD fork. None of these forks are available for Windows.

Does this mean it's not possible to do object detection on the Windows fork or is it just that people prefer not to. Sorry if this is a dumb question but I find the Caffe documentation somewhat lacking when it comes to explaining what features require what fork. I'm using the python interface if that makes any difference.

Thanks for any clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run Caffe-SSD on Windows, but some effort is needed. You need to merge the changes from the Windows branch into the Caffe-SSD. There are some existing solutions for that (https://github.com/runhang/caffe-ssd-windows, https://github.com/gustavkkk/caffe-ssd-win, google for more), but I did not use those, unfortunately. Colleague of mine did it by himself, so it is definitely possible. As soon as you get it compiled and running, you will have a Python interface as well.